# How to edit response data in an Angular service?

Tags: angularjs

```
function _getTagObject() {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8081/tag?limit=1').then(
        function(response) {
            response.data[0];
        });
};
```

I'm trying to only return `response.data[0]`.

Comment: Please comment on how I can make this question better. I will make the necessary edits.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. You just need to return `response.data[0]` from the `then` success callback:

```
function _getTagObject() {
  return $http.get('http://localhost:8081/tag?limit=1').then(function(response) {
    return response.data[0];
  });
};
```

Comment: So, I think my issue here, is that my controller is expecting a promise. When I return data like this, do I resolve the promise?

Comment: @Eric can you show what you've tried in the controller?